# CoordinatorLayout hide toolbar when scrolling only in specific fragment

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using single `Activity` approach with multiple fragments, in the main screen I have `RecycleView` and I want to hide Toolbar when scrolling only in the main screen, since it's single activity and one top level `CoordinatorLayout` the `Toolbar` hides when scrolling in all screens.

How to enable "hide toolbar on scroll" in some screens and disable it for others in single activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yonatan's answer in my case was not enough, when navigating between fragments some views were not visible in the bottom, probably some height misconfiguration.

Enabling and disabling scroll flags for `Toolbar` works just fine.

```
public void disableToolbarScrollBehavior() {
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags(0);
    }

    public void enableToolbarScrollBehavior() {    
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You gotta trace which fragment(screen) is active in your activity and use these functions to hide or show.

```
fun enableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val layoutParams: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = coordinatorLayout.layoutParams 
    layoutParams.behavior = AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior()
}

fun disableLayoutBehaviour() {
    val layoutParams: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams = coordinatorLayout.layoutParams
    layoutParams.behavior = null
}
```